# Getting NaN for a double datatype

Tags: vb.net, double, algebraic-data-types

I am trying to run some mathematical formula which has large values, so I am using the `Double` datatype. But still I am getting the answer as NaN if I input large values. So how can I solve this?

For example, if I pass Varx=3 and countx=1230 I get the result as NaN.

```
Public Function EulerForPro(ByVal Varx As Integer, ByVal Countx As Integer) As Double

    Dim Result1 As Double = 1
    Dim Result2 As Double = Varx
    Dim Result As Double = 0

    For i = 1 To Countx
        Result1 = Result1 + (Math.Pow(-1, i) * Math.Pow(Varx, (2 * i)) / factx(2 * i))
    Next
    For i = 1 To Countx
        Result2 = Result2 + (Math.Pow(-1, i) * Math.Pow(Varx, ((2 * i) + 1)) / factx((2 * i) + 1))
    Next
    Result = Result1 + Result2
    Label2.Text = Result1
    Label3.Text = Result2
    Label4.Text = Result
End Function
```

Comment: One problem you will be having is that double precision numbers are too small to accommodate values such as Math.Pow(3, 2460); About 750 orders of magnitude too small, according to the calculator. What does the `factx` function do?

Comment: factx function calculates the factorial of a number.

Comment: I thought so. That number is also going to be much too large to fit in a double (much larger than the powers you are calculating). I suspect that attempting to divide by `plus-infinity` is the cause of your problem. You need to create your own data type capable of handling such large numbers, find an existing one from somewhere, or change your approach to solving the problem.

Comment: It doesn't help your problem, but this being VB.NET `a^b` is the same as `Math.Pow(a,b)`. Just remember `-1^i` is not the same as `(-1)^i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) of the results. It is standard practice for large numbers.

So instead of multiplying a*b (which causes overflow), use

```
Y = log(a) + log(b)
```

Comment: How to use logarithm in my case? or give an example

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `Decimal` data type instead. It can hold an integer value of approximately `7,9 x 10^28` (the exact number is `2^96 - 1`, since it can use 96 bits of its 128 for storing the integer part of a value). However, it's a complex data type and you should carefully consider how to use it in your code. Not all implicit conversions work, especially when using `Double`.

See [MSDN on decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for exact specifications of `Decimal`.

Comment: Using decimal won't help in this calculation; the maximum size of a decimal is about 1100 orders of magnitude too small to accommodate the numbers in use.

Comment: @BrianHooper Yeah, I didn't check the actual outcomes, but figured it might help to mention `Decimal`.